# download xml Like triposo mobile application ?

Tags: android

i'm trying to create a simple  application that works offline like triposo , i want to download content's from xml api ( text and image ) and show content in list view , how can i do this ? i mean how can i store content ? in sqlite database or xml ? and nobody can see the content except the application . ( image not readable in gallery and text not readable in rooted device ) ? i'm using volley library for communication between server and mobile device .

```
    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

Comment: you can store text in sqlite, images can be stored in cache or internal storage, but if they are large, this could be not good, unless you are periodically clearing old data, other sol, could be storing images in sqlite too, as binary or hex-string? maybe... but this still counted in internal storage so be careful ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triposo uses SQLite for data storage and HTML pages for some of its pages within the app. Note, if you use SQLite or even XML any programmer can still read the content , even iOS apps that use SQLite can be readable.

Triposo stores images as blob in the SQlite tables, something that can still be recovered (I could recover 15 gigs of their data)